# Why .bmp files of same pixels size created with vb.net have different file sizes?

Tags: vb.net, bmp

I'm creating 24 bit .bmp files by assigning a color for each pixel with VB Visual Studio 2017, with a simple code:

Dim TempBitMap As Bitmap 
TempBitMap = New Bitmap(3600, 3600) 
... assign color to some pixels...
TempBitMap.Save(whatever + ".bmp")

The resulting .bmp files are all of different sizes depending on the colors.  All-black files are very small and more coloured files are much bigger.  According to .bmp standards, souldn't they all be the same?.

Tip: Resulting .bmp's can be opened with Paint, but not with PhotoShop. If saved with Paint, then all go to same (and bigger) size.

Actually they work fine when I open them with my software in order to retrieve the values of R, G and B; but I'm just puzzled.  I have the feeling that maybe they are not .bmp files at all, despite their ".bmp" ending.

Can anyone explain this?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the values of 30th through 33th bytes on your files? Then compare them with the BITMAPINFOHEADER compression value expected there. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: You did not create a BMP file.  It is actually a PNG file with the wrong filename extension.  The default image format you get when you call Image.Save(string) without specifying the format you want.  PNG is a compressed format, so it is smaller than BMP and actual file size is unpredictable since it depends on the image complexity.  Use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_) instead.

Comment: Thank you both, guys.  This explains a few things.  On the other hand, it may be a happy accident because the files are smaller but I still can open them as .bmp from within my code, and input the values of R, G and B of each individual pixel (which is the purpose of my code).  I need to double check this, so I'll  learn a little more about PNG's.